# Value won't update in database, no errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Creating an MVC5 app with EF6. I am simply trying to update the db field with a new value. But, it keeps retaining the old value. I checked it in SSMS as well and it shows the old value too. No errors are shown. Here's the code....

```
 private static readonly MyContext Db = new MyContext(); // class-level var
  :
  :
 var EpisodeRecord = Db.Episodes.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == EpisodeId);
  :
 overallScore = sumOfAllPercentages / ar.Count();

 EpisodeRecord.OverallScore = overallScore;  // I verified before and after and it's ok

 try
  {
     Db.SaveChanges();
  }
 catch (Exception e)
  {
     // code never gets here because there's no error
     Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
     throw;
  }
```

I checked the value of EpisodeRecord.OverallScore before and after I set it and it's working.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try changing `Db.Episodes.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == EpisodeId);` to `Db.Episodes.Find(EpisodeId);` and see what happens

Comment: Well you use `AsNoTracking()`, so the entity won't be tracked, and updates to those objects won't be persisted. What happens is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it without AsNoTracking too and it had the same results. But I will try the Find suggestion. (Edited: I mistakenly wrote "with" initially.)

Comment: You mean you tried it WITHOUT the AsNoTracking? That's what you need to do.

Comment: You are relying on ChangeTracking (along with some other kinda unreliable features of EF) in order for your code to work. You should take more control over the statements created (and your context overall, it seems to be ambient) and the time they are sent to the database.